# ASP. Net Core 2.2 with cookie authentication: how to avoid page redirect when not authorized for API only controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My ASP .Net Core **2.2** web application has some controllers that return `View`(s) and some controllers that return a json result as they are just **API** controllers.

My website uses **cookie authentication**, with this declaration:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Pages/AccessDenied";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });
```

In the `Configuration` section:

```
// ...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Pages}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

My `PagesController` just inherits from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` and for some pages I put `[Authorize]` attribute. When a non authorized user tries to open the page it gets correcly redirected to my public `AccessDenied` page. Everything's good.

BUT, I have also an `ApiController`, which inherits from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`, has an attribute `[ApiController]` and also a `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`. I use this controller to communicate with javascript in my pages. The problem is that when a non authorized user tries to invoke the methods on this controller, I don't want it to respond with a HTTP 200 page (the `AccessDenied` one), **but I want that it returns just an HTTP 401 Unauthorized because it is an API.**

How can I achieve such a different behavior keeping the cookie authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: basically you want that, when an unauthorized AJAX call reaches one of your API controllers, the HTTP response is a raw 401 status code right ? (instead of a 302 redirect to the login page or the access denied page)

Comment: Do you only use API controllers for AJAX calls coming from your frontend pages ?

Comment: Yes to both questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to obtain this behavior is writing a custom class which derives from [CookieAuthenticationEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and override both [RedirectToLogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.redirecttologin?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationEvents_RedirectToLogin_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_RedirectContext_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationOptions__) and [RedirectToAccessDenied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.redirecttoaccessdenied?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationEvents_RedirectToAccessDenied_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_RedirectContext_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationOptions__).

If you are not familiar with the `CookieAuthenticationEvents` class you can start from [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#react-to-back-end-changes-1) in the docs. Basically it is a plug point to add custom behavior for the cookie authentication.

First of all you need a way to identify your AJAX requests. The simplest way to do so is using a common prefix in the request path for all of your AJAX requests. As an example you can decide that all of your AJAX request paths will start by `/api`.

You can write the following custom `CookieAuthenticationEvents` class:

```
public sealed class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents 
{
  public override Task RedirectToAccessDenied(
            RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
  {
    if (context is null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.HttpContext))
    {
      context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    else 
    {
      // non AJAX requests behave as usual
      return base.RedirectToAccessDenied(context);
    }
  }

  public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
  {
    if (context is null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.HttpContext))
    {
      context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    else 
    {
      // non AJAX requests behave as usual
      return base.RedirectToLogin(context);
    }
  }

  private static bool IsAjaxRequest(HttpContext httpContext) 
  {
    var requestPath = httpContext.Request.Path;
        return requestPath.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

Now you can register your custom `CookieAuthenticationEvents` with the authentication services inside your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Pages/AccessDenied";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
    });

services.AddSingleton<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
```

Comment: You can also just subscribe to the events by using the provided Events property like this: `options.Events.RedirectToLogin += context => { context.Response.StatusCode = 401; return Task.CompletedTask; }`

Comment: Just setting the status code, still returned the location header (which is ignored by browsers but i did not want), so I added 
`context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized; context.Response.Headers.Location = StringValues.Empty; context.RedirectUri = string.Empty; await context.Response.CompleteAsync();`